# why does the uitextfield never return nil when it becomes first responder?

Tags: iphone, sdk, uitextfield

when i make my textfield become first responder, the text field never returns nil, even if i force it to be nil by myTextField.text = nil;
as soon as i comment out the "[myTextField becomeFirstResponder];" the text field is able to return nil. anybody have any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Becoming first responder initializes the internal NSString that holds the text you type to an empty string: @"", thus no longer nil. Being firstResponder is a persistent action, in order to always have a valid NSString in there when the user begins to type.

Comment: so if i wanted to get the default value of the text field once the it becomes first responder, would it just be literally: @""?

Comment: i found an alternate way that works for me, i just use 
if([myTextField.text length] <= 0]){
[self doStuff];
}

Comment: What value do you expect to get and how do you test for it: put your if statement in the question.